# Database and Data Waehouse design and processing in Big Data

Tags: references, algorithms, large-data, database

With the growing popularity of Big Data and related tools, I am looking for books that specifically deal with implementing a warehouse in one of Big Data technologies, database and data-warehouse designs that are optimized for working with Hadoop, Spark, Hive, HBase or other Map-Reduce based technology.

In other words, I am looking for the equivalent of these books in Big Data frameworks:

- [Star Schema The Complete
  Reference](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071744320)
- [The Data Warehouse Toolkit: The Definitive Guide to Dimensional
  Modeling](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118530802)
- [Fundamentals of Database Systems (7th
  Edition)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0133970779)
- [An Introduction to Statistical Learning: with Applications in R
  (Springer Texts in
  Statistics)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1461471370)

The books that I have found are deal with technical details of Hadoop and related systems such, and do not go very deep into design and algorithms specially optimized for use on Map-Reduce based systems.

I am looking for any book, website, tutorial, course or blog recommendations.

Comment: This is not on-topic for this site I'm afraid. For Spark, the best way to learn is by reading the manuals and blog posts.

Comment: Initially I wanted to ask at Database administrators but it seemed more relevant to ask here. Also the appropriate tags were found here.